# OCaml list syntax error

Tags: list, recursion, ocaml

I am writing a function to remove neighbors from a list which have the same value. I don't understand what the syntax error is here. This is what I have:

```
let rec rem_dup_neighb l = 
let rec rem_dup_neighb_aux l lastseen retl = 
match l with 
 []->retl
|[()]->[()]
| (y::rest) -> if(y==lastseen) then rem_dup_neighb_aux l lastseen retl else rem_dup_neighb_aux l y (y::retl)
in rem_dup_neighb_aux l 9000 [];;
```

I get the following error for the last line of the function:

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
     unit
```

As an example, if you pass in [1;2;2;3;5] to the function, it should return [1;2;3;5]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

UPDATE:
Function seems to be infinite looping:

```
let rec rem_dup_neighb l = 
let rec rem_dup_neighb_aux l lastseen retl = 
match l with []->retl
| (y::rest) -> if(y==lastseen) then rem_dup_neighb_aux l lastseen retl else rem_dup_neighb_aux l y (y::retl)
in
    match l with
    (lastseen::rest) ->  rem_dup_neighb_aux l lastseen []
```

UPDATE 2:
wasn't reducing the problem per iteration. Function seems to be returning [5;3;2] instead of [1;2;3;5] now though.

```
let rec rem_dup_neighb l = 
let rec rem_dup_neighb_aux l lastseen retl = 
match l with []->retl
| (y::rest) -> if(y==lastseen) then rem_dup_neighb_aux rest lastseen retl else rem_dup_neighb_aux rest y (y::retl)
in
    match l with
    []->[]
    |(lastseen::rest) ->  rem_dup_neighb_aux l lastseen []
```

UPDATE 3:

```
let rec rem_dup_neighb l = 
let rec rem_dup_neighb_aux l lastseen retl = 
match l with []->retl
| (y::rest) -> if(y==lastseen) then rem_dup_neighb_aux rest lastseen retl else rem_dup_neighb_aux rest y (y::retl)
in
    match l with
    []->[]
    |(lastseen::rest) ->  rem_dup_neighb_aux l lastseen [lastseen]
```

Comment: Your updated function passes the same list to the recursive call of `rem_dup_neighb_aux` each time. You want the to proceed along the list with each recursive call, so pass `rest` there.

Comment: You're also missing the empty list case in the match at the bottom.

Comment: O right, thanks. Fixed the infinite loop. Hmm, the function is returning [5;3;2] instead of [1;2;3;5]. I see why the first element is getting removed. Also need to reverse the output somehow.

Comment: `List.rev` should suffice for that. (Accumulating a list and then reversing it at the end is quite a common pattern in functional programming.)

Comment: Not allowed to use library functions :/

Comment: Um. :/ Er, I guess you either write your own `list_rev` or transform the code into non tail-recursive form (eg, recursive calls look something like `elt::aux rest elt`).

Comment: Unfortunately we are required to use tail recursion. I'll try to write my own list_rev I guess. First I need to fix the removal of the first element in the list.

Comment: OK, for that look at the `match` at the bottom. Consider what you are doing with the first element.

Comment: I tried to initialize the retl to [lastseen] in the match. I posted an updated version in the original comment. Shouldn't that work? Doesn't seem to be.

Comment: That looks ok, other than the reverse thing. (Passing `rest` instead of `l` in the bottom match will also save one iteration, although the behaviour should be the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The match clause `[()] -> [()]` accepts and produces a `unit list`, which doesn't really make sense there. You probably should have written `[_] -> retl`, `_` being the match syntax for "match anything".

Comment: Ok, what does the ",_" after retl mean on the right side of the arrow?

Comment: So I just removed the [()]->[()] line and changed []->retl to [_]->retl. However, one of the test cases for the function passes in [()] to the function so I get the error: 

Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type
         int
.The error points to the test file

Comment: gsg is saying you should have `[_] -> retl` in your code. He then goes on to point out (after the comma) that `_` is a pattern that matches any value. His punctuation is slightly confusing.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that up. If possible could you address the new problem I have in my previous comment?

Comment: This function compares the list elements to 9000, which constrains things such that it can only accept lists of `int`s.

Answer (score 3):

If one of the test cases has [()] as input, then you can't use 9000 as a fake value for the beginning of the list. You need to have a fake value of the same type as whatever is in the list. One idea would be to use the actual first value of the list.

As a side comment, it seems like you should just take out your second case in the match.  By the second case, I mean the pattern that (after fixing up the code) matches a list of length one; i.e., the pattern `[_]`. With your approach (using a "last seen" value) there are only two cases, for empty and non-empty lists. Your special problems come at the beginning of the list (as you're experiencing now), not at the end.

**Update**

You can have a pattern match (a `match` expression) anywhere you like. So, you can have one after the `in`:

```
let rem_dup_neighbors aList =
    let rec aux l lastseen retl =
        ...
    in
    match aList with
    | pattern1 -> blah blah blah
    | pattern2 -> aux blah blah
```

**Update 2**

When calling yourself recursivelly, you have to pass a smaller problem. Your auxiliary function just keeps calling itself with the same list.

Comment: by second case, you mean the else part of the if statement? Also, do you know how to access the first element of the list without using library functions?

Comment: See rewritten text. Use pattern matching to access list elements.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I would need that for the base case or the function would call itself infinitely.

Comment: Your base case is the *empty* list.

Comment: I thought that is what [_ ]->retl was. I replaced []->retl with [_ ]->retl. Are you saying leave []->retl and remove [_ ]->retl?

Comment: The pattern `[_]` matches a list of length exactly 1. The pattern for an empty list is `[]`, which is the first pattern of your match. Yes, I'm proposing what you say. But you should work it out yourself, don't worry what I say :-)

Comment: ok. Could you point me to somewhere where I can understand/read how to access the first element of the list? Can't grasp how to put pattern matching within the "in" statement. Sorry, I am very new to OCaml.

Comment: Alright, I think I figured out the pattern matching. Function seems to be infinite looping now though. Check original post for updated function.